# Update variable values in opened window

Tags: python, variables, auto-update, spyder

I am using **Spyder**. I am working with several variales which I check by having them open in a separate window. 
My problem is that after each change I have to manually reopen the variable to see the new values. Is there a possibility to **automatically update the variables in the open window**?

Cheers

Comment: Are you using the variable viewer built into spyder? Menu View->Panes->Variable Explorer.

Comment: Exactly. But I mostly work with matrices, therefore I double click the variables in the Variable explorer to see them in a separate window. But, this window is then not updated if the variable change.